# Trying to calculate the width of navigation buttons automatically based on a container

Tags: css, math, navigation, formula

I have for example 3 buttons.

```
<ul id="container" style="width:500px">
    <li>home</li>
    <li>another button</li>
    <li>ok</li>
</ul>
```

I want to find out what the width each button should so that they are spread out in the container.
I tried this but doesn't look so good:

width of the container 500px divided by the total number of characters 20. that gives me 25px for each character

So I make 'home' 100px (4 characters x 25), 'another button' 350 px(14 characters x 25), 'ok' 50px (2 characters x 25) that totals 500px but doesn't look so good. I want the same padding for each button.

my formula looks something like this (not the same padding)

```
|  home  |         another button      | ok|
```

I would like more like

```
|   home    |    another button    |   ok   |
```

any suggestions on the a formula for this?

Comment: Unless you use monospaced fonts, that wouldn't really work.  In most fonts, your 't's will be smaller than your 'o's.

Comment: doesn't have to be perfect. Just close enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this works good:

```
        int containerWidth = 500
        int characterWidth = 9;  //this seems to work ok for a variety of font sizes
        int totalButtons = 3;
        int totalCharacters = 20;
        int allButtonsWidth = (characterWidth  * totalCharacters);  //(=180)
        int pixelsRemaing = ((containerWidth - allButtonsWidth ) / totalButtons); //(=106)
        int leftOvers = (containerWidth - ((totalCharacters * characterWidth) + (pixelsRemaing * totalButtons)));   //  (=2)

        home = (characterWidth * 4) + pixelsRemaing + leftOvers ;    //(=142+2 = 144)
        anotherbutton = (characterWidth * 14) + pixelsRemaing;       //(=232)
        ok = (characterWidth * 2) + pixelsRemaing;                   //(=124) 
                                                                     // total: 500
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't make specific widths for the buttons, I'd just give them identical padding then experiment until the spacing looked right:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbLcP/3/)

Comment: thanks but that's not really an option since fonts look different in different browsers and I need the calculation to be dynamic. The only thing that seems consistent across browsers is using fixed widths.

Comment: The font has a fixed pixel size, as does the padding. The only difference is how you're choosing to apply the fixed values, but applying fixed widths makes it less maintainable if you need to add ui elements.